# Searchresult wrong. Mage::registry('current_layer') not set

Tags: magento

We redesign a magento shop. That shop had a very costumized searchresult page.
Now, after the redesign, the search does not work anymore.
I broke down the problem to the List.php (Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php) where the function `_getProductCollection()` is called to get the results. This function gets a layer `$layer = $this->getLayer();` and there is the main difference to the old version:

```
public function getLayer()
{
    $layer = Mage::registry('current_layer');
    if ($layer) {
        return $layer;
    }
    return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
}
```

In the old version the `Mage::registry('current_layer');` is set. In the new version its not set! And when it is not set it returns a new one `return Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');` with all the products in it.

I can't think any further. How could I find the place where this layer is set in the old version?
What else could I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The search layer model is registered by the `catalogsearch/layer` block, which is usually added to the search page by the `catalogsearch.xml` layout file :

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <label>Quick Search Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalogsearch/layer" name="catalogsearch.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
    </reference>
    <!-- ... -->
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

As it has certainly gone missing, you should add it back to your layout.

Comment: Very good input. the `block type="catalogsearch/layer" ` was out-commented in the layout. How could I oversee that? thx a lot.